# unable to solve 400 POST Bad request

Tags: reactjs

I have created a component which have email, subject and message field as input. My object is to post the input values through POST method but while clicking on the send button - it is showing error as " POST 400 (Bad Request)".

Can anyone help me in this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you using array of email ??

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad - Do i need to use "" instead of array?

Comment: i don't know what you are trying to achieve, in my sense just send email, instead of array of emails..

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad - We need to send multiple emails in one field, so i thought of keeping an array

Comment: go without the array, and tell me if it is working ?? don't forget to change your server side codes..

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad - I don't know about server side coding :( . Now i have changed email : "" instead of [ ]

Comment: added solution, try that..

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad  - i've tried the code, for an example if i type ab then it is showing in this way - " a,ab " but if i copy the email id and paste it there then i could able to send the message

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad - If i copy a email id and paste it in the email input field then it is woking fine but if i type only "ab" then it is showing a, ab, ab,,, ab,,...... an so on upto infinity it going unable to stop the value

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
changeHandle = e => {
    e.target.name ==="email" 
    ?
    this.setState({email:[...this.state.email,e.target.value]})
    :
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
```

Comment: UI Asad -  after trying the above code, for an example if i type ab then it is showing in this way - " a,ab " but if i copy the email id and paste it there then i could able to send the message

Comment: it's showing me `a,ab`, because it's array.. *and i couldn't get the last sentence*

Comment: UI Asad - If i copy a email id and paste it in the email input field then it is woking fine but if i type only "ab" then it is showing a, ab, ab,,, ab,,...... an so on upto infinity it going unable to stop the value